# Start Windows batch file maximized

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I've written a batch file that I plan on distributing to a few dozen machines. It automatically checks the working state of several devices. I recently added a "menu" at the start of the script, prompting the user to select specific items to query from a list. The list, however, is too long to see without scrolling.

Rather than refining my list, what can I **add to the batch** to start the Windows shell maximized? I tried to cheat and `Right click the .bat -> Properties -> Change the "Run" state to "Maximized"`, but this option does not exist (and frankly I'd rather add this feature within the script itself).

The machines that are running the script are running Windows 7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try `start /MAX yourscript.bat` to start your script in a maximized cmd (up to Windows 7)

**Edit** (by Rik):

I've created a small example which shows how you could do it all in one batch-file
(without a separate launcher):

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b

:: here comes the rest of your batch-file
echo "test"

pause
```

There will be a slight flicker of the original batch-file (which will exit immediately) before starting the maximized version.

---

Simple explanation:
If the batch is not called with the parameter `max` we call itself again (`%0`), this time maximized with the help of `start /max`, and **with the parameter `max`** and that way the second time its called it will skip the if-statement and continue with your commands.

Breakdown:

- `if not "%1" == "max"` execute the next command only if `%1` is not "max". `%1` stands for the first parameter given to the batch-file. So `my_batch.bat max` will have `max` in the `%1`-variable. If we didn't start the batch with a `max` parameter we need to execute this line.
- `start /MAX` start the command after it, in maximized form.
- `cmd /c` execute `cmd.exe` and `/c` means exit afterwards.
- `%0 max`. The `%0` stands for your own batch-file name and here `max` is its first parameter. This means we need to skip that first `if`-line or else we get caught in a loop :)
- `& exit/b`: The `&` means execute the next command simultaneous with the previous. This means we executed the `start /max your batchfile` and in the meantime exit the current batch.

This also means we can't call *this version* with any other parameters than `max`. If your batch-files needs a parameter to start then you'll need to do some more magic (like `shift`ing the %1 after testing).
If that's the case let us know.

Comment: This will work, but requires creating a "launching" batch. I'm trying to reduce this to the entire operation running solely off of one file - if possible. +1

Comment: @root you can however create a batch which launches itself with some crafty one-liner at the beginning of the batchfile. Something like `@echo off // if not "%1"=="max" start /MAX %0 max // <rest of the batch>>`. (not tested, but you can see where i am going...)

Comment: @user2196728 I tool the liberty of adding an example to your answer where you don't need a separate launcher-batch. (hope that's alright)

Comment: @Rik : no pb as far as what you wrote sounds good to me :) And it sounds right :)

Comment: @user2196728 No, with `echo "rest of batch"` i just meant that as a placeholder. After the `if not` line you can include your normal batch. (i edited it to make it clearer)

Comment: @Rik : yeah got it, i've updated my previous comment according to your update. Great man ;)

Comment: @Rik Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for after research showed no straight forward solution. Could you maybe break down what the line is actually doing so I can understand how its working more clearly?

Comment: @root I added an explanation and a breakdown of the 'magic'-line. I hope i explained it clear enough. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i'am asking if you can change position of batch file after full screen : like : Win key + left arrow (win+left).

Answer (score 0):

You can maximize the command prompt on during the run but you'll need two additional scripts: [***windowMode***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) and [***getCmdPid.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat):

```
@echo off

call getCmdPid
call windowMode -pid %errorlevel% -mode maximized

some commands
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try mode.com but that only fullscreens it, it does not position the window:

```
@echo off
mode 1000
```

And then enter the code for your batch file.

Comment: This seems not to fullscreen the window, but just to make it very big, while leaving the upper-left corner where it was.

Answer (score -1):

This is extremely useful, one more tweak...

To bring the commmand or batch file's window out of its minimized state to a restored state instead of maximized, i-e, to put the focus on the windows so it shows on screen I slightly modified the command...

if not "%1" == "max" start cmd /c %0 max & exit/b

Snafaru

Comment: It looks like this is sort-of an answer to a different question. Besides, why would we even need to worry about a batch file starting in a minimized window?