# How to launch an app from a minimised Batch File so that it is in focus?

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following code:

```
timeout /nobreak 10
start notepad.exe
timeout /nobreak 5
```

if I run it in a focused Batch File then Notepad launches as the active window. If however I minimise the Batch File  during the initial timeout then Notepad launches in the background. I have to manually alt+tab to it before I can start writing my new text document.

Is there a straightforward way to always launch an app from a bat so it is the active window, irrespective of whether the bat is minimised or not?

Note I have used Notepad here but the above behaviour occurs with all other apps I have tried.

EDIT For claroty, I want the batch file to run minimised, and I know how to run a Batch File minimised. I just want any apps it launches to start focused. As they would have done if the bat itself was in focus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start Windows batch file maximized](https://superuser.com/questions/690296/start-windows-batch-file-maximized)

Comment: That was about maximising the Batch File? I want the Batch File to run minimised, but for any aps it starts to start in focus?

Comment: start /MAX does exactly as you asked for. You just need to adapt it to your usecase EDIT: actually it starts without focus, you are right

Answer (score 4):

It seems like Windows has no built in method for starting a program with focus.

Luckily there are quite a few different options:

### Powershell

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566799/how-to-bring-focus-to-window-by-process-name

### Auto HotKey

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f825794-2c86-427a-b675-8936f2880a79/switch-window-focus-using-a-batch-filecmd?forum=win10itprogeneral

### SendKeys.bat

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988863/using-command-line-batch-to-switch-to-focus-on-app

### VBScript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266840/focus-a-batch-started-application

Comment: thanks for the info. You can also use Nircmd with a "nircmd.exe exec normal ..." command to launch an app focused from a minimised bat. I was hoping for some sort of straightforward internal way without needing 3rd-party tools. But alas it seems not! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TechHorse powershell was integrated the last time I've booted windows.